# Uncaught ReferenceError: getCookieValue is not defined

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Dear community, I ask your help, did here's a [crutch](http://jsfiddle.net/eVta8/2/), it is strange that a modal window with the content does not appear, probably out of the scope of a frame, locally it works. The question is, how to make so that my window is not already appear if a user has a cook. I can not figure out how to add the if(){}. Seems to do everything right. And yet, after adding the conditions, in the *firebag* the entry error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: getCookieValue is not defined**

But this design does not work (location in the body):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var getCookieValue = $.cookie("visit");
        if (getCookieValue == true) {
            $("a.gallery2").fancybox(
                {                       
                    "padding" : 20, 
                    "imageScale" : false, 
                    "zoomOpacity" : false,  
                    "zoomSpeedIn" : 1000,   
                    "zoomSpeedOut" : 1000,  
                    "zoomSpeedChange" : 1000,
                    "frameWidth" : 700,
                    "frameHeight" : 600, 
                    "overlayShow" : true,
                    "overlayOpacity" : 0.8, 
                    "hideOnContentClick" :false,        
                    "centerOnScroll" : false                
            }).click();
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me whether you want to show fancybox only when the cookie is `true` or not. Assuming that fancybox should be shown only if the cookie value is `true`, then try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create cookie "visit"
  var getCookieValue = $.cookie("visit");
  // check if cookie value = true
  if (getCookieValue == "true") {
       $("a.gallery2").trigger("click");
  }
  $.cookie("visit", "true", { expires: 7 }); // set the number of days for cookie
  $("a.gallery2").fancybox({                       
     // API options here
  }); // bind fancybox
});
</script>
```

In this case, the fancybox won't be shown during the first visit but always after the second while the cookie is valid.

On the other hand, if fancybox should be shown **during the first visit only**, then try :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create cookie "visit"
  var getCookieValue = $.cookie("visit");
  // check if cookie value = true
  if (getCookieValue == "true") {
      return false
  } else {
      $("a.gallery2").trigger("click");
  }
  $.cookie("visit:, "true", { expires: 7 }); // set the number of days for cookie
  $("a.gallery2").fancybox({                       
     // API options here
  }); // bind fancybox
});
</script>
```

In both examples, it's assumed that you have this html somewhere in your code:

```
<a class="gallery2" href="path/target"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Accept your answer, so you're more detail in the led solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is undefined the script will fail written that way.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var window.getCookieValue = $.cookie("visit");
        if (window.getCookieValue == true) {
            $("a.gallery2").fancybox(
                {                       
                    "padding" : 20, 
                    "imageScale" : false, 
                    "zoomOpacity" : false,  
                    "zoomSpeedIn" : 1000,   
                    "zoomSpeedOut" : 1000,  
                    "zoomSpeedChange" : 1000,
                    "frameWidth" : 700,
                    "frameHeight" : 600, 
                    "overlayShow" : true,
                    "overlayOpacity" : 0.8, 
                    "hideOnContentClick" :false,        
                    "centerOnScroll" : false                
            }).click();
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: This error shows: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .** 

On this line: **var window.getCookieValue = $.cookie("visit");**

Comment: if I do so, then all :
    var CookieValue = true;
    if (CookieValue == true) {
       $("a.gallery2").fancybox().click();
    }
probably the variable **getCookieValue** not global, and how to make it global? Tried to make a *return* but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Colleagues! Found the solution:

It turns out so, that to compare with variable **getCookieValue** cannot be, because the variable is not *global*, but right once read a *cookie* in condition and compare with the value of the condition.

Here's the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.gallery2").fancybox( {
        "padding" : 20, 
        "imageScale" : false,
        "zoomOpacity" : false,
        "zoomSpeedIn" : 1000,
        "zoomSpeedOut" : 1000,
        "zoomSpeedChange" : 1000,
        "frameWidth" : 700,
        "frameHeight" : 600,
        "overlayShow" : true,
        "overlayOpacity" : 0.8,
        "hideOnContentClick" :false,
        "centerOnScroll" : false
    });

if ($.cookie("visit") == "true") {
    $("a.gallery2").fancybox().click();
}

});
```